# Bash store variable between multiples runs

Tags: bash, variables, export, storage

I would like to increment a variable if an execution failed.

I tested the logic by using a script like:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f "/tmp/init" ]
then
    var=0
    echo $var
    export var
    touch /tmp/init
fi
if [ "$1" -eq 1 ]
then
    (( var++ ))
    export var
fi
echo $var
```

I obtain the result:

```
:~# ./script.sh 1                     
0
1
:~# ./script.sh 1
2
:~# ./script.sh 1
2
```

Is there an easy way to do this stuff?

Comment: You will have to store it in a temp file

Comment: It works by a tmp/file

Comment: But you're not storing your variable in the temp file.  Add an `echo $var > /tmp/init` after your `var++` line.  $var disappears when you come out of your script.  `export` makes it available to its children, not to its parent.